# Solving Wordle using quantum computing

Tags: quantum-algorithms

I have read everything available on how to  solve Wordle using many different strategies ( classical approaches )
However, *I wonder if  Wordle can be approach using Quantum computing to solve the secret in one shot?*
I have thought of Grover's algorithm but I wouldn't be in one-shot.

Comment: Wordle is a word-based version of [mastermind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)). There is reference to quantum mastermind in this pdf [here](https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~dil2008/index_files/quantum_mastermind_abstract_dil2008.pdf), which appears to be a Grover-based implementation.  What makes you think you can solve Wordle in one shot with a quantum computer?  I think you'd definitely need more than one.

Comment: Interesting read on [complexity of Wordle](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.16713).